# Meteor blaze objects not showing

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to display the my tasks object properties as shown in the html page. My tasks have attributes of title and progress. The attributes are not showing however. Is it because of the way I did the map function in my `template.helpers()` is wrong? Thanks

My blaze template

```
<tbody>
    {{#each displayAllTasks}}
        <tr>
            <td class="highlight">
                <div class="success"></div>
                <a href="javascript:;"> {{counter}} </a>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs"> {{ task_item }} </td>
            <td> {{ task_progress }}% </td>
            <td> Bob Marley </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm purple">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

My template is shown below

```
Template
  .personalTask
  .helpers({
    displayAllTasks() {
      counter = 1
      return Tasks.find({}).map(function(item) {
        return {
          task_item: item.title,
          task_progress: item.progress,
          counter: counter++
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: So, you do have `<tr>`s rendered, but without attributes, right?

Comment: What does `Task.find().count()` say?

Comment: I believe your helper's structure is fine (although you could use @index instead of using `counter`). Seems more likely that Tasks.find() isn't finding any documents. Maybe try `console.log(Tasks.find().count())` and, if that doesn't return any documents, check your `collection`, `publish`, `subscribe`, `allow`, and `deny` code.

Answer (score -1):

Does it print any rows?

Anyway i'd do it lile this. You dont need a counter etc.

Template Helper:

```
Template
  .personalTask
  .helpers({
    displayAllTasks() {
      return Tasks.find({})
    }
  })
```

Blaze Template:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each item in displayAllTasks}}
    {{#let counter=@index}}
        <tr>
            <td class="highlight">
                <div class="success"></div>
                <a href=""> {{counter}} </a>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs"> {{ item.title }} </td>
            <td> {{ item.progress }}% </td>
            <td> Bob Marley </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm purple">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/let}}
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

However, if you want counter to be 1 based instead of zero, you will need a helper function for +1. I also removed javascript:; from links.